# Console for command line and debug output both

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I want to divide my console screen into two parts, one showing debug output from the application and other for command line for the same application.
Is there anyway I can do this ?

Thanks

P.S. I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: have you tried gnu screen or tmux?

Answer (score 0):

Best I can think of is using two consoles (separate windows, tabs, or perhaps your terminal emulator supports split screen), and:

- on the first one, run your application and redirect stderr to some file, for example:

  /bin/bash 2> ~/debug.log
- On the second, run:

  tail -f ~/debug.log

Effect: first console shows no error messages and allows normal interaction with your program, second console shows only error channel. If you can modify your 'target' program make sure it uses stderr for debug output.

Comment: this is not what I asked !

Comment: Then explain where I misunderstood your question instead of yelling, would you kindly?

Comment: tmux or gnu screen is the answer.